# Simple SQL Query Builder in JQuery

Tags: jquery, sql, database, generator

I am trying to find a simple query builder interface similar to the SQL Query Builder plugin at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SQL_QUERY_BUILDER, but simpler.

I like it's functionality, but I just want to define the fields, the types, and perhaps some extra information (min and max value) and have a list generated that match the criteria.  Simple ANDs and ORs as well.

Example GUI would be something like:

[SELECT BOX (and/or)] | [SELECT BOX (FIELD NAME)] | [SELECT BOX (Comparison)] | VALUE | [BUTTON ADD]

> ```
>    department = 'SALES'
> ```
>
> AND name like '%SMITH%'

Does a plugin like this exist in JQuery or another Javascript Framework?

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm interested in the same thing.

Answer (score 13):

I've been searching for a while myself now, since I need the same thing.  I found this [expbuilder project](https://github.com/gantir/jsexpbuilder) that seems to be very close to what we need.  It's not actively developed and it doesn't look polished. You can [play around with the UI here](http://expbuilder.googlecode.com/hg/src/cb/condition-builder.html).

Comment: +1 I am looking for something like this. I don't care to use their code but the general layout is helpful for my design. Needs to be cleaner though. Good find.

Answer (score 5):

u can use jquery query builder ,
https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/